# FetchedResultController with UILocalisedIndexCollation

Tags: ios

I am trying to implement something like the contacts page on `iPhone`. 
I tried to use `fetchedResultsController` with `UILocalisedIndexCollation` but they are not working nicely together.

For the UILocalisedIndexCollation, it will use the phonetic names of the chinese characters when determining the sort order, which is what I desire. However, in my fetchedResultsController, even when I set the sort descriptor to localisedCaseInsensitiveCompare, the chinese characters are always the last items. Why are they behaving differently?